# Null @AuthenticationPrincipal user

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to Secure REST server with JWTs. For this purpose I use [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/). All fine, except one thing - I want to get authorized user in the private controllers, when the user already logged in, but getUserInfo method receives user equal to null.

This is private controller, AccountController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/private")
public class AccountController {

    @GetMapping("/getUserInfo")
    public @ResponseBody
    String getUserInfo(@AuthenticationPrincipal final UserDetails user) {// user == null
        return user.getUsername();
    }
}
```

WebSecurity:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private AccountDetailsServiceImpl accountDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(AccountDetailsServiceImpl accountDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.accountDetailsService = accountDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(accountDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
}
```

AccountDetailsServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class AccountDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    private AccountRepository applicationUserRepository;

    public AccountDetailsServiceImpl(AccountRepository applicationUserRepository) {
        this.applicationUserRepository = applicationUserRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<Account> applicationUser = applicationUserRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (applicationUser == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        User user = new User(applicationUser.get().getUsername(), applicationUser.get().getPassword(), emptyList());
        return user;
    }
}
```

Account:

```
@Entity(name = "Account")
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;


    private Account() { }

    public Account(final String username, final String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }


    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

So what is the problem and how can I obtain authorized user using `AuthenticationPrincipal`?

**UPD:**

I tried to use

```
String getUserInfo(@AuthenticationPrincipal final Object user)
```

in my `AccountController`(I changed type of `user` to `Object`) and got **not null object**. After that I tried to obtain the true object type using `user.getClass()` and got `String`. Next I tried to change type of the parameter `user` to `String` in the `getUserInfo` signature and got `String` with the username of the user. So, I can get user info, but with the unsuitable type. I also tried to use `Account` type but also got `null`.

So, now the main question how can I get `user` with `Account` type using `@AuthenticationPrincipal`?

**UPD2:**

Now I also realized that `getUserInfo` gets `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` object, so I think I need to change my `JWTAuthorizationFilter`, but how exactly if `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication()` needs instance of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`?

**UPD3:**

JWTAuthorizationFilter:

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse res,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.

            String user = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(KEY).parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, "")).getBody().getSubject();


            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**UPD4:**

JWTAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal():

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                HttpServletResponse res,
                                FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

    if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        return;
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);
    authentication.setDetails(authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(req));

    Authentication authResult = getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authentication); //BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

Updated version of this method throws `BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials`

Comment: Please add User class implementation also

Comment: @random_user if you mean `User` in `AccountDetailsServiceImpl` then I used `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`, is this correct class?

Comment: @don-prog check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672742/spring-security-adding-a-custom-filter-for-authorization

Comment: @random_user please check the **UPD** section of the question.

Comment: @lzagkaretos I see many OAuth related code, but I don't use it. How can I use this answer?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw you use custom `JWTAuthorizationFilter` and not Spring's implementation. Have you try adding breakpoints in it, to see if it works correctly, when executing a request with an authenticated user?

Comment: @lzagkaretos please check **UPD4**, I think it will provide more information for you.

Comment: @dur thanks! Now I can get `UserDetails`, but I have two questions: **1.** What is the best way to obtain `Account` by username in `JWTAuthorizationFilter.getAuthentication()`? I can't just obtain repository or something via `@Autowired` due to instance of `JWTAuthorizationFilter` is manually created in `WebSecurity`. **2.** How can I get `Account` instead of `UserDetails` using `@AuthenticationPrincipal`? Because if I use `Account` then it is still `null`.

Comment: @don-prog I think you need to use your own filter, your own token und your own provider like https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-kerberos

Comment: @dur is [this](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-spring-security-jwt-mysql-react-app-part-2/) similar to what you mean?

Comment: @don-prog I can't find a custom `AuthenticationProvider` in the linked page and it stil use `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`. However, it uses the `UserDetailsServer`, hence could solve your problem.